# DataTrigger to a control's Validation.HasError

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding, datatrigger

I have a user control which uses the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface and it turns red when it has errors, inside of this user control I put a TextBlock and the following DataTrigger doesn't seem to work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DurationText}"
            Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ActivityUserControl, Path=(Validation.HasError)}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="White">
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

I made sure that the x:Name of my user control is correct (ActivityUserControl), the user control itself turns red when it has errors but the TextBlock's DataTrigger doesn't work (text stays black).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your should set the `Value` of the `DataTrigger` to begin with:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ActivityUserControl, Path=(Validation.HasError)}"
             Value="True">
...
```

You should also make sure that the `ActivityUserControl` is in the same namescope as the `TextBlock` and that it acually contains some validation errors.

You can solve the namescope issue by binding to the parent `UserControl` using the `RelativeSource` property:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

Comment: Yeah forgot to include the Value="True". I added it but the problem still hasn't been solved, I think you're right about the namescope, because when I type "ElementName= " visual studio suggests me names of other controls in the user control but not the user control itself (ActivityUserControl). This TextBlock is a child of the user control and is in the same xaml file, I don't understand why it is not showing up...

Comment: Using RelativeSource has made it work, gotta remember that one. I'm still curious as to why my ActivityUserControl might not be in the same namescope but for now the problem is solved thanks to you.